# perl parsing json value

Tags: json, perl

I have a json output in a file as below

```
{"devices":{"@size":"3","device":[{"@key":"8519","ipAddr":"172.168.2.1",
"name":"sri-asr1000"},{"@key":"1994","ipAddr":"172.17.41.5","name":
"sp-asr9k"},{"@key":"1998","ipAddr":"115.145.9.14","name":"sr-nex10k"}]}}
```

Out of which I want extract name and ip-address in table format.

for example

```
sri-asr1000 172.168.2.1
sp-asr9k 172.17.41.5
sr-nex10k 115.145.9.14
```

I need perlscript for this please help.

Answer (score 4):

```
my $fileContents = '{"devices":{"@size":"3","device":[{"@key":"8519","ipAddr":"172.168.2.1","name":"sri-asr1000"},{"@key":"1994","ipAddr":"172.17.41.5","name":"sp-asr9k"},{"@key":"1998","ipAddr":"115.145.9.14","name":"sr-nex10k"}]}}';
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref();

my $hashTable = $json->decode($fileContents);
print Dumper($hashTable);
```

The JSON library can be found at http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON.

Your output should look something like

`$VAR1 = {
              'devices' => {
                             '@size' => '3',
                         'device' => [
                                       {
                                         '@key' => '8519',
                                         'name' => 'sri-asr1000',
                                         'ipAddr' => '172.168.2.1'
                                       },
                                       {
                                         '@key' => '1994',
                                         'name' => 'sp-asr9k',
                                         'ipAddr' => '172.17.41.5'
                                       },
                                       {
                                         '@key' => '1998',
                                         'name' => 'sr-nex10k',
                                         'ipAddr' => '115.145.9.14'
                                       }
                                     ]
                       }
        };`

From this point, you can easily access each element of the table and print the values.